# How to generate a graph from an excel worksheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel, graph, charts

I am writing code that writes some data to an Excel file using C# (using `Office.InterOp.Excel`).  Now I have to select two columns out of the 10 in the worksheet and plot a graph between the two.  This has to be done using only C#.

Any ideas?  Most examples I found on the net are for fixed data values.  What if the data values are not known before hand?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [ChartObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661351%28v=office.10%29.aspx) class.

For example;

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range chartRange ;  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = 
    (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject myChart = 
    (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "d5");
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Source: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart.htm